# @hapi/wreck res.once is not a function when wreck.post

Tags: hapi.js

When doing this:

```
const user={email:'toto@domain.com'};
const apiRes = await Wreck.post('http://localhost:3000/logged-in', {payload: user});
const body = await Wreck.read(apiRes);
console.log({body});
```

I get this message:

`(node:23384) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: res.once is not a function`

I checked that my other server (`localhost:3000`), answers with a 200 and a body, it's ok.

So I don't know what to do. I based my code on this sample:
https://hapi.dev/module/wreck/#advanced
And it seems that unit test does the same too https://github.com/hapijs/wreck/blob/master/test/index.js#L70

- *node version*: 12.18.3
- *module version*: @hapi/wreck@17.0.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, it seems that i met the most known bug called `stupidity`

Working code:

```
const user={email:'toto@domain.com'};
const {payload} = await Wreck.post('http://localhost:3000/logged-in', {payload: user});
console.log({payload});
```

post shortcut is wrapping request+read calls. Like others shortcuts : https://github.com/hapijs/wreck/blob/master/lib/index.js#L524

Thanks to YoannMa, i got the answer on hapi slack https://hapihour.slack.com/archives/C6BMHNBLM/p1605023760162200?thread_ts=1605022489.160200&cid=C6BMHNBLM